# how to add a dictionary to json file using python

Tags: python, json, openpyxl

I am trying to parse an excel file and i use a while loop but the problem is that it write in the json file only the last data.Can eneyone help me to solve this ans thank you .

```
corpsCBL = {}
i=2
cell = worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=4)
while (cell.value) != "SORTIE":
    cell2 = worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=2)
    if cell2.value is not None:
        corps= {
            "codeArticle": worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=2).value+worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=3).value,
            "produit": worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=4).value,
            "trusquinCB": worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=5).value,
            "trusquin":worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=6).value,
            "longueurCB":worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=12).value
        }
        corpsCBL.update(corps)
        json_object = json.dumps(corpsCBL, indent = 4)
    i=i+1;
    cell = worksheet_corps.cell(row=i, column=4)
# Writing to sample.json
with open("data.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [python dictionary.update()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update):

> update() method adds element(s) to the dictionary if the key is not in
> the dictionary. If the key is in the dictionary, it updates the key
> with the new value.

Therefore, everytime you call `corpsCBL.update(corps)`, the previous entry will be overwritten, since the same key values are already present ("codeArticle", "produit" and so on)

Assuming that you want to collect all entries, you could change corpsCBL to a list and simply append a dict for each excel entry.

```
corpsCBL = []
```

and

```
corpsBDL.append(corps)
```